# Shipping methods in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods

In which table Magento 1.9 stores **shipping methods** like `free shipping` ,`flat rate` ?

Please help to find it out.

Comment: What do you mean my stores shipping methods?

Comment: I want to know the table name where shipping methods and its corresponding codes are stored. I find the code in 'sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate' table but it is order related.

Answer (score 2):

You will get codes and names of sipping methods under core_config_data. Not for all but yes atleast settings will be there. 
You need to run the following sql query in your database:

> SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE '%carriers%';

You will get all shipping carrier related rows will come up like below;

```
carriers/flatrate/active
carriers/tablerate/title
carriers/freeshipping/active
```

and many more.

According to the default shipping methods available in magento 1.9.x

The codes of shipping methods should be middle one of the above text like **flatrate, tablerate, freeshipping** etc.

You can also find the codes from Model of Magento's default Shipping Module in below files:

> app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Freeshipping.php
>
> app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Flatrate.php
>
> app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Tablerate.php

Open these files you will get like below:

```
protected $_code = 'freeshipping';
protected $_code = 'flatrate';
protected $_code = 'tablerate';
```

These are shipping method codes.